# Replace one NSObject with another and save in coredata

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsobject

I am trying to update a NSObject class value I have in coredata however I am not sure how to just update the whole object. This is what I am trying to do

```
for (Items *item in mutableArrayOfSet) {
        if ([updatedItem.rowID isEqualToString:item.rowID]) {

            item = updatedItem;
   }
}
```

item is my none upated Item and updatedItem is of the same NSObject class type which I am trying to use to overwrite the current item in the set... however this line of code

```
item = updatedItem;
```

is giving an error.

> Fast enumeration variables can't be modified in ARC by default; declare the variable __strong to allow this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> item = updatedItem;

This is just setting the value of the iteration variable, it doesn't change anything about `mutableArrayOfSet`.

What you should do is to create a set of changes while you iterate and then save those changes into the source object after the iteration is complete.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is NOT using fast ennumeration. Use a normal `for` loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<mutableArrayOfSet.length; i++)
{
     item = [mutableArrayOfSet objectAtIndex:i];
     ....
     [mutableArrayOfSet replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:updatedItem];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to do what you are suggested by compiler?

```
for (__strong Items *item in mutableArrayOfSet) {
        if ([updatedItem.rowID isEqualToString:item.rowID]) {

            item = updatedItem;
   }
}
```